# Binding XML POJO Class Data Types - Application design

Tags: java, xml, pojo

This question is about application design practice.i am new to application design. I am binding String XML to POJO Objects using DOM parser. Below is my XML syntax.

```
<Message>
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Name></Name> // String Data type
        <Age></Age> // Int data type
        <DOB></DOB> // Date data type
        <Salary></Salary> // double data type
    </BODY>
</Message>
```

From my requirement specification i know the datatypes of each tag in XML. I have created table with respective column with respective datatypes.

Now I am creating POJO classes. My question is, Whether we should create **String** data type variable for all fields [Later casting in DAO layer to respective data types] or I should create **respective data types** for fields in POJO class when binding XML to POJO.

I am thinking how to solve situation with POJO and fields that in application exist in more data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its Not necessary to use only String you can use other datatypes.

you can use casing but if don't worked then it will generate **ClassCastException**
for better practice i prefer same datatype. if its not possible the use casting.

Comment: Noted and Thanks xbadal